# small letter to large java example Shildt

Tags: java, char, type-conversion

```java
char ch;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ch = (char) ('a' + i);
    System.out.print(ch); //<- output small letter
    ch = (char) ((int) ch & 65503); //<-- ???
    System.out.print(ch + "  ");
}
```

Please explain the part of code `ch = (char) ((int) ch & 65503);`

Why do we need 65503 for this?

Comment: This is a hack (and bad coding [magic number]). In general, arithmetic on characters is valid in very narrow ranges so that it's often confusing and not extensible in natural ways. Also, true case changing needs to be locale-specific. See [`String toLowerCase(Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale))

Answer (score 1):

Java uses UTF-16 characters. These characters take 2 bytes. The number 65503 has the bit pattern of

```
1111 1111 1101 1111
            ^       // only the 6th bit is 0
```

As you can see only the 6th bit is 0. When you use this number as a [bit-mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) and do a bit-wise AND operation (your `char & 65503`) it turns the 6th bit of that `char` off (make it a zero).

If you look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (ASCII and Unicode are the same for the Latin alphabet) you'll see that that 6th bit is the difference between capital and none-capital Latin letters (the difference in values is exactly 32). So if you have small Latin characters they will turn into capital character. If you have capital characters it will do nothing, because their 6th bit is already 0. So basically it's a hack to do toUpperCase() on Latin characters.

Comment: I think you are using the term Latin letter too narrowly. This is true for all of the letters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) but only some of the letters in the C1 Controls and Extended Latin-1 block, none in the Latin Extended-1 block, ….

Comment: @TomBlodget I meant the part of the Latin where ASCII and Unicode intersect. Also this question seems to be about an example of usage of bit-masks. Not about Latin in particular.

Comment: Fair enough but the question doesn't say anything about ASCII. As you saw, it uses Java and Java doesn't use ASCII. I do which people teaching concepts of bits, loops and event sorting algorithms with giving misimpressions of what text is about.

Comment: @TomBlodget I wrote that Java uses UTF-16. It's just that www.asciitable.com was the first thing that came to mind to show the relevant characters.